# Cant access function in OOP python

Tags: python, function, oop

For some reason, in my fruit scraper, i cannot access anything from listify function. 
I'am getting an error, for exmaple: `NameError: name 'family' is not defined`. 
And i cant figure out what is wrong with my code - is my function is bad, or i'am doing something wrong with class ?

```
import requests
import json
import random
import pickle

class FruitScraper():

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = []
        self.id = []
        self.family = []
        self.genus = []
        self.order = []
        self.carbohydrates = []
        self.protein = []
        self.fat = []
        self.calories = []
        self.sugar = []

    def scrape_all_fruits(self):
        data_list = []
        try:
            for ID in range(1, 10):
                url = f'https://www.fruityvice.com/api/fruit/{ID}'
                response = requests.get(url)
                data = response.json()
                data_list.append(data)
        except:
            pass
        return data_list


    def listify(self, stats):
        alist = json.dumps(self.scrape_all_fruits())
        jsonSTr = json.loads(alist)
        for i in jsonSTr:
            try:
                self.name.append(i['name'])
                self.id.append(i['id'])
                self.family.append(i['family'])
                self.genus.append(i['genus'])
                self.order.append(i['order'])
                self.carbohydrates.append(i['nutritions']['carbohydrates'])
                self.protein.append(i['nutritions']['protein'])
                self.fat.append(i['nutritions']['fat'])
                self.calories.append(i['nutritions']['calories'])
                self.sugar.append(i['nutritions']['sugar'])
            except:
                pass
        return stats

    def get_summary(self):
        for i in self.listify(zip(self.fat, self.protein, self.calories, self.sugar, self.carbohydrates, self.name)):
            nutr_stats = f'\nNutrients maximum statistics:\nFat: {max(self.fat)}\nProtein: {max(self.protein)}\nCarbohydrates: {max(self.carbohydrates)}\nCalories: {max(self.calories)}\nSugar: {max(self.sugar)}' \
                         f'\nNutrients minimum statistics:\nFat: {min(self.fat)}\nProtein: {min(self.protein)}\nCarbohydrates: {min(self.carbohydrates)}\nCalories: {min(self.calories)}\nSugar: {min(self.sugar)}' \
                         f'\nTotal fruits scraped: {len(self.name)}'
            return nutr_stats



Scraped_info = FruitScraper().scrape_all_fruits()

Listified_info = FruitScraper().listify(family)

Fruits_statistics = FruitScraper().get_summary()
```

It's my first time doing OOP.

Comment: Well, what _do_ you expect to get? And what _is_ `family`? You never declared such a variable in your code. Yet you try to use it, when you call the `listify` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider changing this

```py
Scraped_info = FruitScraper().scrape_all_fruits()
Listified_info = FruitScraper().listify(family)
Fruits_statistics = FruitScraper().get_summary()
```

to

```py
myScraper = FruitScraper()
Scraped_info = myScraper.scrape_all_fruits()
myScraper.listify()
Fruits_statistics  = myScraper.get_summary()
```

Otherwise you create three different objects of this class and discard them with all their attributes after running the individual method once.

This might also be critical to define `family` in this line of the code:

```py
Listified_info = myScraper.listify(family)
```

But I can't see how you intended to use the parameter `stats` in your method `listify()`. It is just received and returned. I suggest that you change:

```py
    def listify(self, stats):
```

to

```py
    def listify(self):
```

and remove

```py
        return stats
```

If you want to get those lists inside the object of this class returned by `listify()`, you may do the following (but this is not OOP way of doing things):

```py
import requests
import json
import copy


class FruitScraper():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = []
        self.id = []
        self.family = []
        self.genus = []
        self.order = []
        self.carbohydrates = []
        self.protein = []
        self.fat = []
        self.calories = []
        self.sugar = []


    def collect_all_lists(self):
        self.allLists = dict('name': self.name, 'id': self.id, 'family': self.family, 'genus': self.genus, 'order': self.order, 'carbohydrates': self.carbohydrates, 'protein': self.protein, 'fat': self.fat, 'calories': self.calories, 'sugar': self.sugar)


    def scrape_all_fruits(self):
        data_list = []
        try:
            for ID in range(1, 10):
                url = f'https://www.fruityvice.com/api/fruit/{ID}'
                response = requests.get(url)
                data = response.json()
                data_list.append(data)
        except:
            pass
        return data_list


    def listify(self):
        alist = json.dumps(self.scrape_all_fruits())
        jsonSTr = json.loads(alist)
        for i in jsonSTr:
            try:
                self.name.append(i['name'])
                self.id.append(i['id'])
                self.family.append(i['family'])
                self.genus.append(i['genus'])
                self.order.append(i['order'])
                self.carbohydrates.append(i['nutritions']['carbohydrates'])
                self.protein.append(i['nutritions']['protein'])
                self.fat.append(i['nutritions']['fat'])
                self.calories.append(i['nutritions']['calories'])
                self.sugar.append(i['nutritions']['sugar'])
            except:
                pass
        self.collect_all_lists()
        return copy.deepcopy(self.allLists)

    def get_summary(self):
        for i in self.listify(zip(self.fat, self.protein, self.calories, self.sugar, self.carbohydrates, self.name)):
            nutr_stats = f'\nNutrients maximum statistics:\nFat: {max(self.fat)}\nProtein: {max(self.protein)}\nCarbohydrates: {max(self.carbohydrates)}\nCalories: {max(self.calories)}\nSugar: {max(self.sugar)}' \
                         f'\nNutrients minimum statistics:\nFat: {min(self.fat)}\nProtein: {min(self.protein)}\nCarbohydrates: {min(self.carbohydrates)}\nCalories: {min(self.calories)}\nSugar: {min(self.sugar)}' \
                         f'\nTotal fruits scraped: {len(self.name)}'
            return nutr_stats


myScraper = FruitScraper()
Scraped_info = myScraper.scrape_all_fruits()
Listified_info = myScraper.listify()
Fruits_statistics = myScraper.get_summary()
```

Comment: While this is true it doesn't solve the problem OP has.

Comment: OP will still get the `NameError` with this code

Comment: With all that done, code still not working.

Comment: Yes, but the fact that OP forgot to define `family` has nothing to do with OOP, while failure to create an object of the class is catastrophic.

Comment: What's the error now?

Comment: Error is the same.

Comment: Please would you mind showing me how exactly you defined `family` in your code, which hadn't been defined.

Comment: I've tried to remove stats and return... Then it give me empty list.

Comment: None of the methods in your class was supposed to return any list. Your `stats` variable didn't collect any list inside the method. Now if you want to access the individual data inside the object of your class, you may use `print(myScraper.genus)` for the list in `self.genus`, for instance, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. How should i improve it then, to return lists ?

Comment: Please, tell me how you want to use that list (save to a file as a table for instance) or it's just a learning of OOP?

Comment: Yes, basicaly it's a task from my coding school. I have to write code, that returns all those list's, some stats of them and so on

Comment: I updated the answer above to reflect that need.

Comment: Thank you a lot ! I really have space where to improve, as i see :))